# convert to decimal in C#

Tags: c#, string, decimal, console.writeline, console.readline

When I use Console.ReadLine(), I input numbers without decimal(2000). Afterwards I need to show this number like decimal number(2000.00), using Console.WriteLine().How to do it?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pEvdWUVmt_mzhycKXG7LVhTCmT5-0Y4k/view?usp=sharing
That is what I need to do
And this is what i did.

```
  using System;
using System.Runtime.Versioning;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace sertifikat
{
    class Program
    {
   

        private static void Main()
        {
            Console.Write("Broj racuna:");
            string brojRacuna= Console.ReadLine();
           
            Console.Write("Prodavac:");
            string ime = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Cena proizvoda:");
            string cp = Console.ReadLine();
            double cenaProizvoda = Convert.ToDouble(cp);
           
            
            double pdv = cenaProizvoda / 5;
            Console.WriteLine("PDV: $" + pdv);
            Console.WriteLine("--------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Ukupno: $" + (cenaProizvoda + pdv));
            Console.Write("Uplata:");
            double uplata = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Uplaceno: $" + uplata);
            if (uplata < (cenaProizvoda+pdv))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Niste uplatili dovoljno novca.Potrebno je da uplatite jos $" + (cenaProizvoda+pdv - uplata));
                
                Console.Write("Uplata:" );
                float uplata2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Uplaceno: $" + uplata2);
                Console.WriteLine("Ukupno uplaceno:" + (uplata+ uplata2));
                Console.WriteLine("Kusur:" + ((uplata+uplata2)-(cenaProizvoda+pdv)));
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ukupno uplaceno:" + uplata);
                Console.WriteLine("Kusur:" + (uplata-(cenaProizvoda+pdv)));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("***Hvala na poseti***");
           
           
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: See: [Standard numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) and/or [Custom numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings). I'd also recommend to use [Double.TryParse Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=net-7.0) in favor of `Convert.ToDouble`

Comment: Oh, and of course you should know [When you should use floating point for money](https://medium.com/@navpil/when-you-should-use-floating-point-for-money-yes-you-read-it-right-178b6dd8102e)

Answer (score 0):

`decimalVar.ToString("0.00");`

Comment: A high quality answer would explain why this is what OP wants and maybe where he can find documentation. Maybe you want to add this.